Process of Derivative of Fourier Transform in Partial Differential Equation
I'm reading the book 'Spectral Methods for Incompressible Viscous Flow' by Roger Peyret.

While reading this, there is tiny part that I can't understand although it looks like simple.




When $u_K(x, t)$ is defined like below,
$$u_K(x, t)=\sum_{k=-K}^{K}\hat{u_k}(t)e^{\underline{i}kx}$$
where $\underline{i}$ is imaginary number and k represents mode.




Bottom equation
$$\frac{u_{K}^{n+1}-u_{K}^{n}}{\Delta t}+u_{K}^{n}\frac{\partial u_{K}^{n}}{\partial x}-\nu \frac{\partial^{2}u_{K}^{n+1}} {\partial x^{2}}=0$$
can be rewritten as below.




$$(\frac{1}{\Delta t}+\nu k^{2})\hat{u_{k}}^{n+1}=\frac{1}{\Delta t}\hat{u_{k}}^{n}-\hat{\omega _{k}}^{n}$$
where
$$\hat{\omega _{k}}^n=\underline{i}\sum_{\substack{p,q=-K,\\p+q=K}}^{K}q\hat{u_{p}}^n\hat{u_{q}}^n$$



I think $\hat{\omega _{k}}^n$ is corresponded to $u_{K}^{n}\frac{\partial u_{K}^{n}}{\partial x}$.

But I can't understand why $\hat{\omega _{k}}^n$ is shown like this.

Let me show derivation process that I've done for $\hat{\omega _{k}}^n$



$$\frac{\partial u_{K}^{n}}{\partial x}=\sum_{k=-K}^{K}\underline{i}k \hat{u_k}(t)e^{\underline{i}kx}$$
$$\therefore u_{K}^{n}\frac{\partial u_{K}^{n}}{\partial x} = \sum_{k=-K}^{K}\hat{u_k}(t)e^{\underline{i}kx} \sum_{k=-K}^{K}\underline{i}k \hat{u_k}(t)e^{\underline{i}kx}$$

Because index $p$ is repeated two times although they're different to each other, one of them should be changed into $q$

$$\therefore u_{K}^{n}\frac{\partial u_{K}^{n}}{\partial x} = \sum_{k=-K}^{K}\hat{u_k}(t)e^{\underline{i}kx} \sum_{q=-K}^{K}\underline{i}q \hat{u_q}(t)e^{\underline{i}qx}$$

Although I've derived until here, I can't understand why it can be expressed like below.

$$\hat{\omega _{k}}^n=\underline{i}\sum_{\substack{p,q=-K,\\p+q=K}}^{K}q\hat{u_{p}}^n\hat{u_{q}}^n$$

I don't know why $\sum$ and $e$ terms can be rewritten like that way.

Thank you :)

This comes from the fact that the Fourier series of a product is the convolution of the Fourier series
